# SIAlertView freezes app

Tags: ios, swift, freeze, sialertview

SIAlertView sometimes freeze application on dismissal of alert view.

When clicking one of the buttons, even "Cancel" or any button, the handler block executed and everything seems to be in order, except that the UI becomes non-responsive, and I have to kill the application.

I'm using CocoaPods.

Can anyone suggest how to debug this issue or solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/jsauve/SIAlertView.Xamarin/issues/3

Comment: @beyowulf i am working in ios and not xamarin. do you have any solution for ios?